# Is there a way to open a new panel everytime a button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a panel that has 3 textareas for a user to add certain information. It then goes through the process of being saved to the database. On every click of a button, I want the same empty panel to appear which will allow the user to enter multiple entries

Answer (score 0):

I put together this little code for you, hope it helps you

```
//Simple HTML with 3 textarea
<div>
    <form action="">
        <textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
        <textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
        <textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
        <span id="btn">Click me!</span>
    </form>
</div>
```

So anytime the button #btn is clicked, first the form is submitted and then the textarea is cleared.

```
// The Javascript
const
    btn = document.querySelector('#btn'),
    form = document.querySelector('form'),
    textarea = document.querySelectorAll('textarea')

function clearFields() {
    for (let i = 0; i < textarea.length; i++) {
        textarea[i].value = '';
    }
}

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    // functionality to asynchronously submit and save user entry to DB
    submitFormToServer()

    // Clear all the textarea
    clearFields()
})
```

Answer (score -1):

After button click event you could call a Redirect to the same page which will clear out the textboxes or explicitly clear them out (Textbox1.Text = "" etc.)

Comment: I don't want to clear them out. After they are saved, the panel stays visible and the textareas just go into readOnly.  on button click, I want the same panel to appear, but with empty textareas, so the user can add multiple entries.

Comment: your write says you wanted to clear out the values so user can add more entries. you were not accurate in that. And even now you say you want to mark them READONLY but allow for multiple values?  Please re-read your request and revise it so we can understand exactly what you are trying to do.